# How to correctly export a Pygt-graph into a .svg file?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

i'am trying to export a pyqt-plot into a .svg file, but only an empty graph gets shown.

The Graph itself and its contents is initalized like so:

```
        self.ramp_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.ramp_widget.setBackground('w')
        
        self.first_pd = self.ramp_widget.plotItem
        self.first_pd.setLabels(left='axis 1')
        
        self.second_pd=pg.ViewBox()
        self.first_pd.showAxis('right')
        self.first_pd.scene().addItem(self.second_pd)
        self.first_pd.getAxis('right').linkToView(self.second_pd)
        self.second_pd.setXLink(self.first_pd)
        self.first_pd.getAxis('right').setLabel('axis2', color='#0000ff')
```

as it is described in pyqtgraph/examples/MultiplePlotAxes.py...

The actual plotting i'am doing with the following function:

```
def plotting (current_index, means2, means3)
        self.updateViews()
        self.first_pd.plot(current_index, means2, pen='b')
        self.second_pd.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(current_index, means3, pen='r'))

def updateViews():

        self.second_pd.setGeometry(self.first_pd.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
        
        self.second_pd.linkedViewChanged(self.first_pd.vb, self.second_pd.XAxis)
```

I have tried 2 different solutions:

```
       exporter = pyqtgraph.exporters.SVGExporter(self.ramp_widget.scene())
       #here i also tried self.ramp_widget.PlotItem
       exporter.export(save_directory)
```

This will display the Graph itself correctly (two seperated y-axis), but without any contect.

when doing it like with the following code:

```
        combined_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        combined_widget.setBackground('w')

        # Set labels for the combined plot
        combined_widget.plotItem.setLabels(left='axis 1', right='axis 2')

        # Add plots to the combined widget
        combined_widget.plotItem.plot(self.current_index, means2, pen='b')
        combined_widget.plotItem.getViewBox().addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(self.current_index, means3, pen='r'))

        # Export the combined plot as SVG
        exporter = pg.exporters.SVGExporter(combined_widget.plotItem)
        exporter.export(save_directory)
```

the content gets shown, however the the graph does not have a seperated y-axis.

Is there a simple solution that i just don't see?
Or do i need to modify the combined graph manually to get the right display?

I'am still quite new into PyQt so i would be glad if someone could also give a small explenation behind my mistakes and the solution.

Comment: Post a [mre] and I'll answer.